# Java method and Big Complexity

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity

I am currently revising some past exam papers on Data structures and algorithms and I have come over a question I can't seem to wrap my head around. Can anyone help me here please? Or even point me in the right direction? Thanks.The question is below.

"Consider the Java method below. How many lines will be printed
out when n is 10? How about when n is 100? In light of this,
derive an expression for how many lines will be printed out in
terms of the input parameter n. State the Big O complexity of the
method and prove that this is the case using the mathematical
definition."

```
public void method (int n){
  for(int i = 0; i < (n - 5); i++) {
    for(int j = 1000; j > n; j--) {
      System.out.println("One step");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you could always reduce the numbers, run it, and extrapolate from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tricky. Since the inner loop will be executed at most 1000 times (assuming n must be positive), you can say it runs a constant number of times. The outer loop runs n-5 times, which is O(n).

Therefore the total running time is `O(n)`.

For small values of n (< 1000), the inner loop runs `1000 - n` times, but that doesn't make a difference on the asymptotic running time, since that number goes to 0 when n is higher than 1000.

> How many lines will be printed out when n is 10? How about when n is 100?

Those numbers have no relation to "the Big O complexity of the method", since for most values of `n` the number of lines printed would be 0.